# Order of security checks for incoming email

Tags: spf, dkim

Team,
I would like to know the order in which checks like ( spf check, reverse DNS check, DKIM check) are performed for incoming email. Is this vendor product specific??

If particular order is followed, the reason for it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karthik, It's vendor specific, but  SPF and DKIM have to be done before DMARC. But I normally see SPF, DKIM, DMARC as the typical order. rDNS is more of a spam check vs an authentication check.

But there's a lot more checks then you mention, take a look at all the checks [this tool](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) does.

Comment: Thank you Henry, that helps